# How to incrementally refresh Azure Analysis Services having synapse pool as source. Does "Default" processing option supports incremental refresh

Tags: azure-analysis-services, azure-synapse

- Cube: Tabular (Azure Analysis Server)---
- Source DB: Azure Synapse Pool ---
- Data Operation: Insert and update is happening on the source system

#### Issue:

Not able to get latest data from synapse pool in AAS cube, using "Default" processing option.

#### Clarification:

1. Which processing option(except full) to use, to have the latest data updated in tables in the cube?
2. Does "Default" processing option supports incremental refresh on tables in cube?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked/answered over on the Microsoft Q&A forums: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251394/how-to-incrementally-refresh-azure-analysis-servic.html

To summarize:

- Default processing does not refresh any data, only loads in tables that have not already been processed
- Incremental processing isn't currently a supported feature in Azure Analysis Services. Instead, [use partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/partitions-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions) to segment data so you only need to reload the most recent changes.